# How to determine if ExecuteReader returned a result set or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

I'm working on a concept to retrieve the Schema from an executed stored procedure. The goal is to loop through multiple stored procedures to generate a data dictionary.

I have a CLR Assembly that's retrieving the data. For performance reasons, the stored procs have parameters automatically generated to produce no rows so the expectation is to get an empty result set that I can retrieve the schema from. The issue I'm running in to is that it's possible for a stored procedure to be passed into the function that does not have a result set. I need a way to handle and identify these stored procedures.

Here is the function:

```
    public static void Return_ColumnData(SqlString query)
    {
        DataTable schema = null;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
        string sQuery = query.ToString();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sQuery, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                reader.Close();

                string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO #tmpColData (ColumnName, Length, Precision, Scale, DataType) SELECT @ColumnName, @Length, @Precision, @Scale, @DataType";

                foreach (DataRow myField in schema.Rows)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection))
                    {
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = myField[0].ToString();
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Length", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(myField[2]);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Precision", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(myField[3]);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Scale", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(myField[4]);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = myField[24].ToString();

                        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe.Send(exception.Errors[0].Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

If I don't handle it it will throw this error from the stored procedure that calls the assembly (Return_ColumnData):

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.Procedure2DataDict, Line 236 [Batch Start Line 0]
6522  A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "Return_ColumnData":
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException:
   at Procedure2DataDict.Return_ColumnData(SqlString query)
```

I tried adding a reader.HasRows to determine whether or not there was a result set but it will return false if there is no result set and if there is 0 rows which does not work for me.

```
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                } else
                {
                    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Failed to get schema. No rows output.");
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                    return;
                }
```

I have to assume something to handle no result set with ExecuteReader() exists. I know there is a difference between ExecuteReader() and ExecuteNonQuery() but since the function will be run for an iteration of multiple procedures, I don't know beforehand if the proc will return a result set or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use FieldCount.

From [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):
Executing a query that, by its nature, does not return rows (such as a DELETE query), sets FieldCount to 0.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the answer was staring me in the face in the form of the error I was receiving.

The error message is a NullReferenceException so I've decided instead of checking HasRows to just ensure the result of GetSchemaData() != null.

```
                if (reader.GetSchemaTable() != null)
                {
                    schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                } else
                {
                    SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Failed to get schema. No rows output.");
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                    return;
                }
```

I've tested for my cases and it is working as expected.

I understand there are probably multiple ways to handle this and people can still contribute with an explanation of their method.

Thanks!